# List the updated files without using go build again

Tags: go, mux

I am just starting with Go. I've a question regarding gorilla/mux.

I am trying to list out the files inside a directory; and the response will be sent back from GET request to list the files.
Now, when I create a new file inside directory; the GET request doesn't list the new file.
I understand I need to run go build again. Can I do it without building it again ?

```
type Images struct {
    Image     string `json:"image"`
    Path      string `json:"path"`
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    Labels    string `json:"labels"`
    Version   string `json:"version"`
}


var images []Images


func getImages(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(images)
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(os.Args[1])

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        images = append(images, Images{Image: file.Name(), Path: os.Args[1]})
    }
    fmt.Println(images)

    // Route handles & endpoints
    r.HandleFunc("/images", getImages).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application reads the list of files at startup. To update the list of files, you must restart the application.  You do not need to run `go build` to get an updated list of files.

To get an up-to-date list of files on every request, read the list of files in the request handler function:

```
func getImages(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", 500)
        return
    }

    var images []Images
    for _, file := range files {
        images = append(images, Images{Image: file.Name(), Path: os.Args[1]})
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(images)
}
```

Remove the corresponding code from `main()` and the `images` package-level variable.